# For a subspace $A$ of $X$, defining relative homology group $H_n(X,A)$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

So we define $H_n(X,A):=C_n(X)/C_n(A)$,the quotient space, where $C_n(X):=$ free Abelian group generated by all singular $n-$maps $\Delta^n\to X$.

I don't understand the following:

Elements of $H_n(X,A)$ are represented by relative cycles: $n-$ chains $\alpha \in C_n(X)$
such that $∂α \in C_{n−1}(A)$.

How does this follow from the definition?

Take $[\alpha]\in H_n(X,A)$. How to ensure that there exists a $\beta\in C_n(X)$ such that $[\alpha]=[\beta]$ and $\partial \beta\in C_{n-1}(A)$?

Comment: The relative cohomology is not defined by that quotient though.

Comment: @ArcticChar: I don't know what cohomology is. My question is strictly about homology. Co-homology in tags is because no other tag seemed to fit here.

Comment: Ar I meant homology. $H_n(X,A):=C_n(X)/C_n(A)$ is wrong.

Comment: @ArcticChar: Oh, you're absolutely right. $C_n(X,A)= C_n(X)/C_n(A)$ and using these chain complexes, we define homology groups (relative). Thank you so much. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An element $a\in H_n(X,A)$ is represented by an element of $Z_n(X,A)$. These are in particular elements of $C_n(X,A)=C_n(X)/C_n(A)$, so there is an $\alpha\in C_n(X)$ such that $a=[\alpha+C_n(A)]$. The condition that $\alpha+C_n(A)\in Z_n(X,A)$ is to say that $\partial\alpha+C_{n-1}(A)=\partial(\alpha+C_n(A))=0+C_{n-1}(A)$, i.e. $\partial\alpha\in C_{n-1}(A)$.

Comment: Can you please explain what $Z_n(X,A)$ is?

Comment: It's the $n$-cycles of the chain complex $C_{\bullet}(X,A)$.